# Laravel get data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a pivot table of users_operators.
I want to grab the operator_id of the user.

This is how i do this now, but its seems like verbose way.

```
if (Auth::user()->type === 'operator') {
    $user = Auth::user();

    // There is a better way to do this?
    $operator_id = $user->operator[0]['pivot']['operator_id'];

    Session::put('operatorId', $operator_id);
}

class Operator extends \Eloquent
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}

class User extends \Eloquent
{
    public function operator() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Operator');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm, battling insomnia and not functioning at 100%, but you should be able to get away with `$user->operator->id` based on what I'm interpreting your models to be (it looks like you had a typo when you copied them into the question).

If that doesn't work, you might want to check out the "Dynamic Properties" section in the [Eloquent docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) for more info, if you haven't already.

Comment: Im getting Undefined property  $operator_id when i do this. 
$user = User::find(57);
dd($user->operator->operator_id);

Comment: Try `$user->operator>id` instead. You don't need the `operator_` prefix as you're referencing the Operator model, and not the pivot table.

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Comment: Try `$user->operator->first()->id`. 

Edit: looks like you fixed your models. I think using `first()` on the returned collection should work.

Comment: Call to a member function first() on a non-object